# Can you use the model selection criteria AIC and BIC for logistic regression?

Tags: regression

I understand that AIC and BIC are common methods for model selection for linear regression. My question is: can these same methods be used for logistic regression as well? Is there a better model selection method for logistic regression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  AIC and BIC should work reasonably well for any models where there is a clear definition of the likelihood (or likelihood density).

Things get more complicated for (1) hierarchical models (where the count of "number of parameters" depends on the level of focus) and (2) quasi-likelihood models (people do use quasi-AIC based on quasi-likelihood, but it's debatable).